# Sklearn PCA is pca.components_ the loadings?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Sklearn PCA is pca.components_ the loadings? I am pretty sure it is, but I am trying to follow along a research paper and I am getting different results from their loadings. I can't find it within the sklearn documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pca.components_` is the orthogonal basis of the space your projecting the data into. It has shape `(n_components, n_features)`. If you want to keep the only the first 3 components (for instance to do a 3D scatter plot) of a datasets with 100 samples and 50 dimensions (also named features), `pca.components_` will have shape `(3, 50)`.

I think what you call the "loadings" is the result of the projection for each sample into the vector space spanned by the components. Those can be obtained by calling `pca.transform(X_train)` after calling `pca.fit(X_train)`. The result will have shape `(n_samples, n_components)`, that is `(100, 3)` for our previous example.

Comment: Transform applies dimensionality reduction according to the documentation so my vector has a different shape then the components.I am just trying to replicate a paper and its this one specifically http://ftp.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-rotations-pretty.pdf  I need the loadings to perform a Varimax rotation so I can build out table that has corresponding variables to each components.

Comment: If you don't want to reduce the dimensionality you can just pass `n_components=n_features` to the PCA constructor (this is the default I think) and the results of the call to transform will have shape `(n_samples, n_features)` as well (assuming `n_samples > n_features)`.

You can also choose to pass `whiten=True` or `whiten=False` (to the PCA constructor) to decide if you want to rescale the "loadings" to have unit variance or not.

Comment: Please read the source code of the class if you need more details on how transform works, it's not very complicated: 

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working with it a little too superficially and dug into PCA technique a little more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

This previous answer is mostly correct except about the loadings. components_ is in fact the loadings, as the question asker originally stated. The result of the fit_transform function will give you the principal components (the transformed/reduced matrix).