# Clarifying the meaning of "loadings" using Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I've been reading about PCA in sklearn, specifically the relationships between features and components. I am particularly interested in identifying feature importance with respect to a couple of principle components. However, I found a few posts that say different things.

For instance, in the 3 answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217710/factor-loadings-using-sklearn) are discussed eigenvectors and loadings. Particularly, it is [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728692/1379826) that `pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_)` shows the component loadings of the features. Why is `sqrt` used here?  And why the product?

However, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845697/1379826) it is indicated that `abs(pca.components_)` gives you the feature importance in each component. This seems to contradict what is indicated above, yes? [This blog post](https://www.datavedas.com/dimensionality-reduction-in-python/) also indicates that `pca.components_` is the component loading of each feature.

Additionally, I miss to understand how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386315/1379826) answers the question: `"I think what you call the "loadings" is the result of the projection for each sample into the vector space spanned by the components. Those can be obtained by calling pca.transform(X_train) after calling pca.fit(X_train)."` But this is not correct: loadings pertain to the *coefficient* of each feature on the principal components, and not samples. Agree?

Would really appreciate some clarification in here.